# C# : asp.net 3.5 : Deserialize JSON - json string or object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i have posted how to deserialize a json in c# but this is my question:

i got this json string :

```
data = @"[{""ShiftID"":""2"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfs""},{""ShiftID"":""4"",""EmpName"":""dsdsfd""}]";
```

and my code can deserialize it perfectly but well, if i receive this type :

```
data = @"[{
  "Q6Option": null,
  "Q5Comments": "",
  "EndDate": "01/17/2012 12:57",
  "Q4Comments": "",
  "Active": 1,
  "Q3Comments": "",
  "Q8Option": null,
  "Q2Comments": "",
  "StartDate": "01/17/2012 12:57",
  "Q3Option": null,
  "Q5Option": null,
  "Q1Comments": "",
  "Q2Option": null,
  "Station": "B1",
  "Q7Option": null,
  "SyncDate": null,
  "ID": 1,
  "Q8Comments": "",
  "Q4Option": null,
  "ShiftID": 1,
  "EmpName": "CSM FName",
  "Q1Option": null,
  "Q7Comments": "",
  "SyncStatus": 0,
  "Q6Comments": "",
  "EmpID": "111",
  "createdAt": "2012-01-17T20:58:17.956Z",
  "updatedAt": "2012-01-17T20:58:17.956Z",
  "objectId": "XERFM5KrGv"
}]"
```

it doesnt work because of there is missing ""..

Well if you have an idea , thanks!

Comment: Which tool do you use to deserialize/serialize?

Comment: Issue can be due to `StartDate`/`EndDate` values - JSON Serializers in .NET expect date/time to be formatted in the specific way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScriptSerializer class that are supported from .NET framework 3.5

Reference link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Sample link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx

There are some sample json texts that are same as your issue:

{"__type":"Shape:#MyApp.Shapes","x":50,"y":70}

Comment: i tried but i cannot put this json string into a var or a string it doesn't work... it need "" in front of each attribute...